# Increment number with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery `animate` for incremente random number `0001 to 1000` but if number is `0077` the final number is `77` what is the solution for have format like `0077` plz ?

Thanks you

```
var $date = $("#date");
  $({someValue: 0000}).animate({someValue: 0077}, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing:'swing', 
      step: function() { 
          $date.text(Math.round(this.someValue));
      }
  });
```

Comment: Why would you need to?  You can always have it be submitted as XXXX and it will remove any unnecessary (leading) 0s without any issues.

Comment: I need this format for application with `slice()` its work great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may meet your needs:

```
$date.text(("0000" + Math.round(this.someValue)).slice(-4));
```

For example:

```
("0000" + 77).slice(-4);
```

gives 0077.

Comment: This is good one: http://jsfiddle.net/sLmfu8a9/

Answer (score 2):

you can use a function like this

```
function fill (N) {
  N = N.toString();
  return N.length < 4 ? fill("0" + str, 4) : N;
}
```

the number 4 is the number of digits that need your string like  4 in your case...